# Sitecore send workflow emails

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

I want to configure Sitecore Workflow engine for email sending.

I had a look into the "Email Action" implementation using Reflector,

It reads "mail server" from argument as follows.

```
string host = this.GetText(innerItem, "mail server", args);
```

Don't we need to provide credentials(Username/Password) for mailserver? Or does it take mail configuration from the webconfig?

I have not tried email sending with Workflow yet, Please help me to configure email sending module.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore reads the mailserver settings from the following properties in the web.config:

```
<setting name="MailServer" value="your.mailserver.com" />
<!--  MAIL SERVER USER
      If the SMTP server requires login, enter the user name in this setting
-->
<setting name="MailServerUserName" value="" />
<!--  MAIL SERVER PASSWORD
      If the SMTP server requires login, enter the password in this setting
-->
<setting name="MailServerPassword" value="" />
<!--  MAIL SERVER PORT
      If the SMTP server requires a custom port number, enter the value in this setting.
            The default value is: 25
-->
<setting name="MailServerPort" value="25" />
```

This should be enough to send emails from Sitecore and webforms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It reads your mail settings from the web.config.  In addition to all of the Sitecore mail settings you need to configure you should also add the generic ASP.NET mailSetting at the bottom of your web.config.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="127.0.0.1" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: I have never had the need to add this setting to the web.config on any of the Sitecore sites I have build in the last 7 years...